# What options exist to restore tab completion using libedit in PSQL on OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, open-source

It would appear that Apple have managed to get it utterly wrong with libedit *again*. The version shipped with Lion is apparently broken, and consequently tab completion doesn't work in psql ([Discussion here](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/libedit-memory-stomp-is-apparently-fixed-in-OS-X-Lion-td4621521.html)). psql is one of the few tools that I tend to use directly from my macbook rather than on a vm and it would be lovely if it just worked. I've tried rlwrap and although it functions it doesn't support psql tab completion. I suppose I could install a new version of psql from source and link it directly against readline but I was wondering if:

1. ...anyone had found a workaround of some sort
2. ...it was even vaguely credible to consider building an updated version of libedit and replacing the system version?

Answer (score 1):

Install macports, and then install the postgresql83 package.

sudo port install postgresql83

The macports psql works fine. Make sure you get it first on your path, e.g.:

PATH=/opt/local/lib/postgresql83/bin:$PATH